# Laravel check login and Auth::check() in all of requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel, 4 I'm checking the login session using `Auth::check()` in all of my controllers. This is not good for my project, so I'm try to check the user login session in all of requests and responses instead, by using a filter:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

How can I check the login session without using `Auth::check()` in routes and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your routes.php like following

```
Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'), function()
{
Route::get('something','HomeController@something');
});
```

In your filters.php bring changes to redirect to your desired route

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
if (Auth::guest())
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::guest('your_desired_route');
    }
 }
 });
```

So here login is checked in filters.php not routes.php or controllers.

Comment: @ Zahan-Safallwa thanks sir, must be define `Route::group` in `route.php` ?

Comment: Yes. But it is routes.php not route.php :) @mahdipishguy

Comment: You may accept the answer so that other can get benefited while searching for solution of same problem

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that you have an infinite redirect loop. `App::before` will apply to *every single request*.... including the request to `Redirect::route('login')`.

Thus upon redirecting to the login page, you immediately redirect again to the login page, and so on. Your browser will detect the infinite redirect, stop it, and tell you `The page isn't redirecting properly`.

One way to get around this is to use the `Request::is()` method to detect whether you are already on the login page. If you are, don't redirect again.

```
if (!Auth::check() && !Request::is('login')) {
    return Redirect::route('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with your redirect page. You just change

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
         return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
    } else {
         return View::make('login')
    }
});
```

Comment: where to place this function in laravel?